# Add blob of html inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden input field with values in it, and I have the following code. Inside the span (`<span class="telephone">&nbsp;<span>`) , I need the hidden field value to show up . I think my javascript code has errors.. How do I add a blob of html code inside javascript?

```
   <input type="hidden" name="mobile" value="04323242445"/>
    <script>    
var dateFrom =new Date(2014, 2, 3);
var dateTo = new Date(2014, 3, 1);
var dateCheck = Date.now();
if((dateCheck < dateFrom) ||(dateCheck >dateTo)){ 
    document.write("
//I need the below text to show up 
<div class="virginMobileError">
<br/>
<p class="first">THE OFFER HAS EXPIRED FOR <span class="telephone">&nbsp;<span> AND THE CUSTOMER CAN NO LONGER REDEEM THEIR GIFT.</p>
<br/>
<p class="second"><span class="rep">Rep script:</span> "Unfortunately all offers have an end date and this one has ended. We can still change you to Virgin Yes Please to
ensure that you can receive future offers from us."</p>
</div>
");
}
```

Comment: Chance the opening and closing `"` by `'` and it should work.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `document.write` to create HTML (except in certain cases).

Comment: You should use `document.getElementsByClassName('telephone')[0].innerHTML = "the text you need to show up."` instead of `document.write("")`;

Comment: It's a kinda more complex solution, but I'll just mention some people put any "HTML templates" they have in their own files, and use a library like Mustache to import them into a page. As for adding a value as an argument, Mustache supports those too. It's still very doable with inline code, but if this is a frequent task for you, consider a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of inserting elements: (Note that you do not need to have an `id` since `name` is already enough for identify individual inputs.)

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/hfj4T/

```
var dateFrom = new Date(2014, 2, 3),
    dateTo = new Date(2014, 3, 1),
    dateCheck = Date.now();

if( (dateCheck < dateFrom) || (dateCheck > dateTo) ){ 

//---------------------------------------

var hiddenEle = $("input[name=mobile]");

$("<div>").addClass("virginMobileError").append(
    $("<br>"),
    $("<p>").addClass("first").html("THE OFFER HAS EXPIRED FOR <span class='telephone'>" + hiddenEle.val() +"<span> AND THE CUSTOMER CAN NO LONGER REDEEM THEIR GIFT."),
    $("<br>"),
    $("<p>").addClass("second").html("<span class='rep'>Rep script:</span> \"Unfortunately all offers have an end date and this one has ended. We can still change you to Virgin Yes Please to ensure that you can receive future offers from us.\"")
).insertAfter(hiddenEle);

//---------------------------------------

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do multi-line string literals in javascript by escaping the newline character with a back slash

```
   <input type="hidden" name="mobile" value="04323242445"/>
    <script>    
     var dateFrom =new Date(2014, 2, 3);
     var dateTo = new Date(2014, 3, 1);
     var dateCheck = Date.now();
     if((dateCheck < dateFrom) ||(dateCheck >dateTo)){ 
       document.write('\
         <div class="virginMobileError"> \
         <br/> \
         <p class="first">THE OFFER HAS EXPIRED FOR <span class="telephone">&nbsp;<span> AND THE CUSTOMER CAN NO LONGER REDEEM THEIR GIFT.</p> \
         <br/> \
         <p class="second"><span class="rep">Rep script:</span> "Unfortunately all offers have an end date and this one has ended. We can still change you to Virgin Yes Please to \
         ensure that you can receive future offers from us."</p> \
         </div>');
     }
     </script>
```

Comment: This won't work. You have double quotes inside double quotes.

Comment: addressed the quote escaping bug and inline comment removal